# Curl Post request Array in field

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use an API where I am trying to use multiple images but with a single image the api code works fine but when I use the following code for working with multiple images, I get error (check error log). I am not sure how to fix this and yes I have tried the solution already on stackoverflow with

```
$field_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

and using the same in

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);`

but that did not fix the issue

My code:

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['filesx'];


//set POST variables
$url = 'http://c.docverter.com/convert';
$fields = array('from' => 'html',
    'to' => 'pdf',
    'input_files[]' => "@/".realpath('example_files/'.$filename).";type=text/html; charset=UTF-8",

    //'other_files[]' => "@/".realpath('example_files/dasd.png'), works

    'other_files' => array(
        '@/'.realpath('example_files/182078images.jpg'),
        '@/'.realpath('example_files/dasd.png')
        )
);

//$field_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$finalx = strstr($filename , '.html', true);

$fp = fopen('uploads/'.$finalx.'.pdf', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=justchecka.com/'.$finalx.'.pdf&embedded=true"
      </script>';
```

Error Log:

```
[19-Mar-2017 19:49:37 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/markdown_to_pdf.php on line 23
[19-Mar-2017 19:49:37 Etc/GMT] PHP Stack trace:
[19-Mar-2017 19:49:37 Etc/GMT] PHP   1. {main}() /home/markdown_to_pdf.php:0
[19-Mar-2017 19:49:37 Etc/GMT] PHP   2. curl_setopt() /home/markdown_to_pdf.php:23
```

Comment: uncomment this variable `$field_string` and then use it directly in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);`

Comment: @hassan I did that as I mentioned in the post. It did not work error log is not updated but I do not get required output so still the issue is not resolved for me.

Comment: then, send your other files as follows: `'other_files[]' => "@/".realpath('example_files/182078images.jpg'), 'other_files[]' => "@/".realpath('example_files/dasd.png');`

Comment: @hassan I tried that as well but it took the second image only not the first when I did that. Anything else I can do?

Comment: manually index them, `other_files[0]` and `other_files[1]`

Comment: @hassan no bro it did not work that way also. I tried it.